# sum of fractional functions optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Consider the following sum of fractional functions optimization problem
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\min }\limits_{\bf{x}} \,\,\,\sum\limits_{i = 1}^p {\frac{1}{{{\bf{a}}_i^T{\bf{x}} + {b_i}}}} \\
subject\,\,to:\,\,\,{\bf{x}} \in X
\end{array}$$

where ${{\bf{a}}_i^T{\bf{x}} + b}>0$  and $X$is a non empty compact convex set. How can I solve the optimization problem?

Comment: [tag:fractional-calculus] is a completely different matter, hence I removed the tag. For the problem: What else do you know about $X$? Is the objective function self-concordant on $X$? If so, you can apply standard convex optimization theory.

Comment: What do you mean about the objective function is self-concordant on X?l am looking for an algorithm to solve the problem with Cvx because Cvx can not solve the problem!

Comment: This question is duplicated, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417537/minimization-of-sum-of-linear-fractional-functions